# CRD creation with java-client for Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

IS it possible to create custom resource definition by reading the data from yaml file and using [Java client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java) for Kubernetes?
I am using the version of library 3.0.0 in sbt and with Scala. But I was not able to find any kind of methods for custom resources creation in the main library repository while there are similar methods for the basic resources (like pods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, But not only with java client.
So first use some lib to read yaml and convert it to JSON.
And then USe K8s [api for Custom Resource Object](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/openapi/apis/CustomObjectsApi.java) or what ever you want to do.

Comment: The above link https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/src/test/java/io/kubernetes/client/apis/CustomObjectsApiTest.java does not work anymore. Is there a way to apply the CRD using k8s java client.

Comment: @Imran.vatic is it what you looking for? https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/main/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/CRDExample.java